# Elementary proof that the category of modules is not self-dual

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

If $R,S$ are rings such that ${}_R \mathsf{Mod}$ is equivalent to ${}_S \mathsf{Mod}^{\mathrm{op}}$, then $R$ and $S$ are trivial. This is well-known. The usual proof uses of the notions of limit and colimit. Namely, one observes that for directed families of monomorphisms $(M_i \to M)$ and monomorphisms $N \to M$ the canonical morphism
$\mathrm{colim}_i (M_i \times_M N) \to (\mathrm{colim}_i M_i) \times_M N$
is an isomorphism in ${}_R \mathsf{Mod}$, but almost never in ${}_S \mathsf{Mod}^{\mathrm{op}}$. This is also connected to the observation that the abelian category ${}_R \mathsf{Mod}$ satisfies AB5, but not AB5*, unless $R=0$.

**Question.** Is there a more elementary proof that ${}_R \mathsf{Mod}$ and ${}_S \mathsf{Mod}^{\mathrm{op}}$ are only equivalent for trivial $R,S$ which does only use the concepts of category, functor, natural transformation, initial/final object, and of course equivalence of categories, but *not* limit/colimit, and also *not* monomorphism/epimorphism?

If not: What happens in the special case that $R,S$ are two fields, i.e. we consider vector spaces? Can we find a simple proof then?

*Background*: I write a text on category theory which contains the statement. I don't want to "sell" this statement as something "deep" which really depends on limits and colimits, without being sure that we really need them. If possible, I would like to move the statement from the chapter on (co)limits to the chapter on functors, natural transformations and equivalences of categories, because it *seems* to be so elementary. Notice for example that one can rather easily show that $\mathsf{Set}$ and $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ are not equivalent.

Comment: You consider the notion of natural transformation more elementary than the notion of monomorphism?

Comment: In any case, one context in which to place this result is the following more general result: categories of modules are locally presentable (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category), and the opposite category of a locally presentable category is locally presentable iff it's a poset.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't think you can avoid limits and colimits, in one way or another. The duality between finite dimensional vector spaces shows you need infinite “processes” to prove that the category is not self dual. I'd suggest the AB5 property, which deals with the lattice of submodules, which you already mentioned.

Comment: With such limited tools, maybe it would be appropriate to set your sights a bit lower and pick a specific module category that you want to show is not self-dual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Categories of modules and opposites of such categories can be distinguished by the behavior of the natural map $\bigoplus_i M_i \to \prod_i M_i$ from a countable coproduct to the corresponding countable product. In categories of modules this map is a monomorphism but usually not an epimorphism, while in their opposites this map is an epimorphism but usually not a monomorphism. I think that's pretty elementary.